# How do I insert special characters in to Azure table storage with "az storage entity insert"-command?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have a Powershell script that builds a "az storage entity insert" command dynamically. Basically I have a CSV file that I use to create the content of a table by converting it to a long command it then invokes. It has worked fine until I added a field that contains a Regexp.

I started to get strange "The system cannot find the path specified." errors. Not from accessing the CSV as you would first suspect, but from running the command generated. I found out that some special characters in the field's value breaks the command and it tries to execute what comes after that as some separate command or something.

I made the expression simpler and found that not much characters work. As simple commands as this does not work:

```
az storage entity insert --table-name table --account-name $StorageAccountName --if-exists replace --connection-string $StorageConnectionString --entity PartitionKey=ABC RowKey=DEF Field="(abc)" Field@odata.type=Edm.String
```

This causes a different error "Field@odata.type was unexpected at this time."

Also | character causes problems, like:

```
az storage entity insert --table-name table --account-name $StorageAccountName --if-exists replace --connection-string $StorageConnectionString --entity PartitionKey=ABC RowKey=DEF Field="|abc" Field@odata.type=Edm.String
```

gives "'abc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This instead works fine:

```
az storage entity insert --table-name table --account-name $StorageAccountName --if-exists replace --connection-string $StorageConnectionString --entity PartitionKey=ABC RowKey=DEF Field="abc" Field@odata.type=Edm.String
```

So why do those special characters break the command and how can fix it? I need both of those characters for the regexp and some others too that won't work.

These errors happen both when I run directly from Powershell as well as in my script that uses Invoke-Expression

Comment: You can refer to [Use Azure CLI effectively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively) and  [Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought this had to do with the way that PowerShell [handles single quotation marks vs double quotation marks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1) but it turns out that I was only half way there.  [Octopus Deploy lists several solutions](https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping) including this with wrapped single quotes:

```
'"(abc)"'
```

Here are your original commands and then your commands with the wrapped single quotes around double quotes (where I now instead error out on failing to provide an account name):

[image]